# frame around the selected area to the script in Illustrator

Tags: illustrator-scripting

[image]

```
var idoc = app.activeDocument;  

var sel = idoc.selection;  

var blk_color = new CMYKColor();  
blk_color.cyan = 100;  


for (i=0; i<sel.length; i++) 

{  
    var pgItem = sel[i];  
    var bounds = pgItem.geometricBounds;  

    var ipath = idoc.pathItems.rectangle
    (pgItem.position[1],
    pgItem.position[0],
    pgItem.width,
    pgItem.height);  

    ipath.stroked = true;  
    ipath.strokeColor = blk_color;  
    ipath.filled = false;  
    ipath.strokeWidth = 5;  
    ipath.strokeDashes = [10];
}
```

Comment: This is a basic scripting question and not really design related. All you need to do is change the parameters of `rectangle()` accordingly.

Comment: The hardest part is that Illustrator internally works with points only, so you will have to devise some way of recalculating 15mm to a point value.

Comment: I could not CAI and  Rad Lexus ..Can you help..are you the author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rectangle` method of `pathItems` takes the parameters `(top,left,width,height)` so all you need to do is offset those values accordingly.

Illustrator works exclusively with points so you need to convert the value from mm to points. 2.834645 points = 1 millimeter so...

15mm = 42.52point (rounded to 2 decimal places)

This should work:

```
var ipath = idoc.pathItems.rectangle(
pgItem.position[1]+42.52,
pgItem.position[0]-42.52,
pgItem.width+85.04,
pgItem.height+85.04);
```

Comment: you couod have put the calculation to a variable instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the corners aligned in this script?